# How can I identify a SharePoint user inside a REST service

Tags: rest, authorization

For my **Intranet** application, I am using a 3rd party Javascript library inside my SharePoint page. The widget I want to use accepts a REST service function that it can use, but it does not allow for any parameters.

**I am writing the REST service and inside the service I need to know who the caller is.** As it's an Intranet application, I know the user is logged in to my network.

Is it possible to determine the user from inside my REST service by configuring the correct security?

**Can anyone show me what to put in my web.config? And will this be testable from Visual Studio or will I have to deploy it to my server to see it work?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You should create your REST service using Provider-hosted add-in model and use SharePoint context information. PnP Sites Core library can help you with that as it provides SharePoint context action filter and helper class for WebAPI.

[Good sample](https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices-detail/1930)

Before calling web service, you will have to redirect user to provider-hosted app to register OAuth 2.0 access token and refresh token in cache and then you can redirect user back. You can try to open app in hidden iFrame instead of redirecting.

If you use SharePoint on-premise, you can create WCF REST Service in farm solution and use context information from `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` without bothering with OAuth.

[More info](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24194.sharepoint-2013-create-a-custom-wcf-rest-service-hosted-in-sharepoint-and-deployed-in-a-wsp.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for that idea. We are SharePoint on-premise, but I have never built a farm solution. I was hoping to be able to do it with configuring a REST service that is deployed to a non-SharePoint server.

Comment: If you use SharePoint on-premise, then creating WCF REST Service in farm solution would be definitely easier. I have added good article to my answer.

Comment: If you can't deploy web service to SharePoint Server, then you have to use SharePoint add-in.